# How to reset a form after clicking submit button by using react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, I am trying to reset a form after clicking submit button in react but its not working. I am using useRef hook to reset a form after clicking submit button.
But is not working properly. so someone please help me how to reset a form after I click submit button.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './Signup.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Signup() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const testData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/user', data);
            console.log(res);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }


    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
        const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value });
        setData(newData);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(data);
        testData()
    };

    const myForm = useRef(null)
    const resetForm = () => {

        myForm.current.reset();

        }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                    <div className='col-4'>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='firstname' id="firstname" name='firstname' onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='lastname' id="lastname" name='lastname' onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder='email' id="email" name='email' onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder='password' id="password" name='password' onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <button ref={myForm} onSubmit={resetForm} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `ref` is to be applied on the `form`

Comment: try setData({field1:null, field2:null,..})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={myForm}>
```

and

```
<button
  onClick={resetForm}
  type="submit"
  className="btn btn-primary"
>
```